# Docker on Windows permission denied when git stash a file

Tags: windows, git, docker, hyper-v, moby

With the latest version of Docker for Windows.
I got a php git repository that 2 of my containers use.
I modify a random file on the host : README.md

Then I do these git command one after the others :

```
git stash # ok
git stash pop # ok
git stash # ok
git stash pop # ok
git stash : => Takes 1 minute, then :
error: unable to create file README.md: Permission denied
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

I also noticed that from inside the container :

```
root@317635dc4f03:watch -n 1 head README.md
Every 1.0s: head README.md                                                                                                                                             
Thu Aug 10 16:27:37 2017
head: cannot open 'README.md' for reading: Stale file handle
```

Then

```
head: cannot open 'README.md' for reading: No such file or directory
```

On the Window host the file is visible but I can't open it neither delete it (permission denied)

I need to stop docker, stop the Hyper-V MobyLinuxVM, and wait to be able to restore the README.md file with a `git reset --hard`
Is there any way to avoid this kind of file sharing problem ?

Docker 17.06.0-ce |
Windows 10 pro : 15063.540 |
Hyper-V : 10.0.15063.0 |
Moby, trusty,